# Whats wrong with my code? It's giving exception

Tags: java, runtime-error

I have written this code as I want to print 5 lowest numbers in a row out of 7 numbers, but don't want to print duplicate values. Now its giving some exception.

What to do with this?

I think I need a dynamic type of `Arraylist` but I don't know apply that exactly.

```
class mycode{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean lowStraightFound = false;
    int firstCard=0 ;
    int firstCardIndex = 0;
    int lastCard =0;
    int lastCardIndex = 0;
    int c[]={1,2,3,3,4,5,7};
    int[] inarow = new int[20];
    int index[]=new int[5];
    int last=0;

    int num = c.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       int card = c[i];
        if (lastCard!= 0) {
            int lastOrd = lastCard;
            int cardOrd = card;
            if (cardOrd - lastOrd  == 1) {
                inarow[0]++;
                lastCardIndex = i;
                last++;
                index[last]=i;   
            } else if (cardOrd - lastOrd != 0) {
                inarow[0] = 1;
                firstCard = card;
                firstCardIndex = i;
                last=0;
                index[last]=i;
               }else if(cardOrd - lastOrd == 0){
                  index[last]=i;
                  last=i;  
               }
        } else {
            firstCard = card;
            firstCardIndex = i;
            index[last]=i;
        }
        lastCard = card;

        if (inarow[0] == 5) {
            lowStraightFound = true;
            break;
        }          
    }
        for (int i = last; i >= 0; i--) {
          System.out.println(c[i]);
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why not provide the exception it is giving?

Comment: remove empty lines in your code. Tell us where the exception is thrown. remove all other code that is unnecessary to explaining your problem.

Comment: What do you see when you step through you code in your debugger.

Comment: Copy the array to a set ( to remove duplicates ), sort the set ... and take the first 5 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
last++;
index[last]=i;
```

should be changed to

```
index[last++]=i;
```

to avoid [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get an [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

To prevent this, line 28, change this:

```
index[last]=i;
```

into this:

```
index[last++]=i;
```

Or change line 14:

```
int index[]=new int[5];
```

into this:

```
int index[]=new int[6];
```

Since your index goes up to 5 (array size - 1)